# Get extra attribute value from 'has_many through' association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have the following structure:

In my `answer` model:

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answer_test_case_results
  has_many :test_cases_result, through: :answer_test_case_results, source: :test_case
end
```

My `answer_test_case_result`:

```
class AnswerTestCaseResult < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :answer
  belongs_to :test_case

  def get_output
    output
  end
end
```

My `answer_test_case_result` model has an extra attribute, named `output`. In my `answer` model I would like access this `output` from my `test_cases_result` relationship, however the way it is this attribute returns only the `test_case` objects saved and associated with this answer.

There is a way to access the `output` without a query directly from my AnswerTestCaseResult (that is, `AnswerTestCaseResult.where(answer: answer, test_case: test_case)`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scarcity of examples of this kind of operation is unbelievable. But now I understand what I was doing wrong: I should access my `has_many :answer_test_case_results`, not `has_many :test_cases_result, through: :answer_test_case_results, source: :test_case`.

And if I want to leave the attribute, for my case, more appropriate semantically, I can use: `has_many :test_cases_result, class_name: "AnswerTestCaseResult"`

So I can access `output` through `answer.test_cases_reult.first.output`, for instance.